# Avast Blocks Internet Sharing over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-security, internet-sharing

I have a WiFi wireless adapter(TP-Link TL-WN 721N). I use it's SoftAP mode to share internet over wifi to my tab though the tab can connect to the network, it cannot access internet. if I disable my internet security(Avast Internet security), there's no problem. I think that avast firewall is blocking it.  How I can share my internet over wifi without disabling my IS?

Comment: Please don't label it as a duplicate( of this question http://superuser.com/questions/674786/unable-to-share-internet-by-using-hostednetwork-after-installing-avast-recently)

Comment: Can you tell your firewall not to block the WLAN addresses or not to block the wireless adapter itself?

Comment: @Fred That's what I am looking for, I don't know how to do that. Please Guide me on doing so.